# Do not concatenate text display with set text, use android resource instead?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,@Nullable ViewGroup container,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
     textview=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.position);
     Bundle bundle=getArguments();
         if(bundle!=null){
             System.out.println("not null");
             textview.setText("The Page Currently Selected is"+bundle.getInt("position"));
            }
     System.out.println(" null");
     return layout;
```

In the code above, it says DO NOT CONCATENATE TEXT DISPLAY WITH SET TEXT,USE ANDROID RESOURCES INSTEAD, also, my viewpager is not working, it is not showing my fragment, I believe it has something to do with this, any suggestions?
Below is the rest of my main activity, i set up my viewpager but it wont work with my fragment or when i load it????

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private ViewPager mPager;
private SlidingTabLayout mTabs;
private static final String KEY_FRAGMENT="position";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_appbar);

    mToolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    NavigationFragment drawerlayout=(NavigationFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation);
    drawerlayout.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation,(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout),mToolbar);
    mPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    mTabs=(SlidingTabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    if(id==R.id.navigate){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, NavigateTo.class));
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    String[]tabs;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        tabs=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        MyFragment myFragment=MyFragment.getInstance(position);

        return myFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabs[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
    //constructing a fragment class in the MainActivity(UPDATE THIS)
}
    public static class MyFragment extends Fragment{
        private TextView textview;
        //in position represents the position that is shown inside the          fragment
        public static MyFragment getInstance(int position){
        MyFragment myFragment=new MyFragment();
            Bundle args=new Bundle();
            //UPDATE PUT A KEY IN FOR "position"
            args.putInt(KEY_FRAGMENT,position);
                    myFragment.setArguments(args);
            return myFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,@Nullable ViewGroup container,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
            textview=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.position);
            Bundle bundle=getArguments();
            if(bundle!=null){
            System.out.println("not null");
                textview.setText("The Page Currently Selected is"+bundle.getInt("position"));
            }
            System.out.println(" null");
            return layout;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use try-catch to wrap textview.setText("The Page Currently Selected is"+bundle.getInt("position"));.

Answer (score 1):

two things here.

First, you should use the resources string and formatting methods.
In res/strings.xml add the current line

```
<string name="resource_id">"The Page Currently Selected is %d$1"</string>
```

Thus, in your code you can use the getString method

```
getResources().getString(R.id._resource_id, bundle.getInt("position"));
```

more information here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling

For the second point, it is not linked to the previous warning, there should be something more that I didn't notice. perhaps your textView's color is the same color of your background making it invisible.

Comment: No, that did not work and yes they are different colors, myviewpager is just no responding at all